# How can I know the dimension of my variable?

Tags: python

I get this error :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (365,) (2,)
```

But I'm surprised by this (2,).
How do I know which variable does this dimension (2,) please? 
Because none of my variables should have it.

Thank you for your help !

Here, you can see the first script, where I define my function. It include a loop and also another function so I don't know if I can. 
I have a lot of variable with (365, ) for the dimension because, it's function of the time, so for 365 days. 
I have some fixed variable like the soil parameter, so the dimension for these is (1,)
But I don't know which variable get (2,) dimension ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def SA(MO = 0,
          ETPr = 0, 
          SWSa = 0,
          pb = 1.70  ):

    DB = pd.read_excel("~/Documents/Spider/Data/data_base.xlsx", sheet_name = "DB")
    DB1 = pd.read_excel("~/Documents/Spider/Bilan_Courgette.xlsx", sheet_name = "sol")
    DB2 = pd.read_excel("~/Documents/Spider/Bilan_Courgette.xlsx", sheet_name = "culture")
#Calculs inter. pour déterminer ET0/day

#Array qui reprend "date" en une série 1 -> 365
    JourDeLAnnee = pd.Series(range(1,366))

#Mauves
    dist_TS = 1+(0.033*np.cos(0.0172 * JourDeLAnnee))
    decli_So = 0.409*np.sin((0.0172 * JourDeLAnnee)-1.39)
    lat = 0.87266463
    ang_Hor_So =np.arccos(-np.tan(lat)*np.tan(decli_So))
    gamma = 0.067
#Jaunes
    delta = 2504*np.exp((17.27*DB.tsa_by_day)/(DB.tsa_by_day +237.3))/(DB.tsa_by_day +237.3)**2
    rg = DB.ens_by_day / 1000000 * 86400
    ra = 37.6 * dist_TS * ((ang_Hor_So * np.sin(lat) * np.sin(decli_So)) + \
                       (np.cos(lat) * np.cos(decli_So) * np.sin(ang_Hor_So)))
    rso = (0.75 + (2*0.00001*120)) * ra
    tw =(DB.tsa_by_day * np.arctan(0.151977 * ((DB.hra_by_day + 8.313659)**0.5))) + \
    np.arctan(DB.tsa_by_day + DB.hra_by_day) - np.arctan(DB.hra_by_day - 1.676331) + \
    (0.00391838 * ((DB.hra_by_day)**1.5) * np.arctan(0.023101 * DB.hra_by_day)) - 4.686035
    ed = (0.611 * np.exp((17.27 * tw) / (tw + 237.3))) - (0.0008 *(DB.tsa_by_day-tw) * 101.325)
    ea =((0.611 * np.exp((17.27*DB.tsa_max) / (DB.tsa_max + 237.3))) + \
         (0.611 * np.exp((17.27 * DB.tsa_min) / (DB.tsa_min +237.3)))) / 2.0
    rn = (0.77 * rg) - (((1.35 * (rg / rso)) - 0.35) \
                        * (0.34 - (0.14 * (ed**0.5))) * (4.9E-9) * ((((273+DB.tsa_max)**4)+((273+DB.tsa_min)**4))/2))

#Calcul de G
    from typing import List
    def get_g_constant(tsa_by_day: List[float], day: int):
        assert day >= 1
        return 0.38 * (tsa_by_day[day] - tsa_by_day[day-1])
    def get_g_for_year(tsa_by_day: List[int]) -> List[float]:
        g_list = []
        for i in range(1, len(tsa_by_day)):
            g_value = get_g_constant(tsa_by_day, i)
            g_list.append(g_value)
            return g_list

    G = get_g_for_year(DB.tsa_by_day)
    G = [DB.tsa_by_day[0]] + G

#Le fameux ET0
    ET0 = ((0.408 * delta * (rn - G)) + (gamma * (900 /(DB.tsa_by_day + 273)) * DB.vtt_by_day * (ea - ed))) / \
        (delta + (0.067*(1+(0.34 * DB.vtt_by_day))))


# Calcul des paramètres du sol
    Profil = 500
    pb = 100 / ((MO / 224000) + ((100-MO) / (1.64)))
    Os = 0.6355+0.0013* DB1.A -0.1631* pb
    Or = 0
    lnα = (-4.3003) - (0.0097*DB1.A) + (0.0138* DB1.S ) - (0.0992*MO)
    lnn = -1.0846-0.0236 * DB1.A -0.0085 * DB1.S +0.0001 * (DB1.S)**2
    nn = np.exp(lnn) + 1
    m = 1 - (1/nn)
    lnK0 = 1.9582 + 0.0308*DB1.S - 0.6142* pb - 0.1566*MO
    λ = -1.8642 - 0.1317*DB1.A + 0.0067*DB1.S
    α = np.exp(lnα)
    K0 = np.exp(lnK0)
    θPf2 =(((1 + ((α*(10**2.5))**nn))**(-m))*( Os - Or)) + Or
    θPf4 =(((1 + ((α*(10**4.2))**nn))**(-m))*( Os - Or)) + Or
    SWS = θPf2 - θPf4
    diff = SWS*SWSa
    aj = diff / 2 
    θPf2New = θPf2 + aj
    θPf4New = θPf4 - aj

#Calcul du volume de stock p à atteindre

    p = 0.04 *(5 - ET0) + DB2.ptab[0]
    θp =(1 - p) * ( θPf2New - θPf4New )+ θPf4New
    Vp = θp * Profil

    #Le fameux ETP
    import datetime
    DateS = datetime.datetime.strptime('30/03/2019','%d/%m/%Y').timetuple().tm_yday
    DateR = datetime.datetime.strptime('15/09/2019','%d/%m/%Y').timetuple().tm_yday

    ETP=ET0.copy()
    for n in range(364):
        if n >= (DateS - 1) and n <= (DateR - 1) :
           ETP[n] = ET0[n] * DB2.Kc[0]
        else:
           ETP[n] = ET0[n] * DB2.SolNu[0]

    ETP[0] = 0

    ETPNew = ET0.copy()
    ETPNew = ETP - ETP * ETPr

    #Le Bilan Hydrique
    Stock = ET0.copy()
    θ = ET0.copy()
    Drainage = ET0.copy()
    Irrigation = ET0.copy()
    Se = ET0.copy()
    SeC = ET0.copy()

    θ[0] = θPf2New
    Stock[0] = θ[0]*Profil

    for i in range(364) :

        Se[i] = (θ[i] - Or)/( Os - Or)

        if Se[i] > 1 :
            SeC[i] = 1
        else:
            SeC[i] = Se[i]

        Drainage[i] = K0 *(((SeC[i])**λ )*(1-(1- SeC[i]**(nn/(nn-1)))**m)**2)*10

        if Vp[i] - Stock[i] > 0 :     #Ici stock non défini
         Irrigation[i] = Vp[i] - Stock[i]
        else:
         Irrigation[i] = 0

        Stock[i+1] = Stock[i] + DB.plu_by_day[i] - ETPNew[i] - Drainage[i] + Irrigation[i]

        θ[i+1] = Stock[i+1] / Profil

    return (Irrigation.sum())
```

After, i use a second script to do a sensitivity analysis. And It's here, when I run this script, I get the error 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (365,) (2,)'

```
import numpy as np
from SALib.analyze import sobol
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from test import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up dictionary with system parameters
problem = {
  'num_vars': 4,
  'names': ['MO', 'ETPr', 'SWSa', 'K0'],
  'bounds': [[0, 10],
             [0, 0.04135],
             [0, 0.2615],
             [1.40, 1.70],
             ]}

# Array with n's to use
nsamples = np.arange(50, 400, 50)

# Arrays to store the index estimates
S1_estimates = np.zeros([problem['num_vars'],len(nsamples)])
ST_estimates = np.zeros([problem['num_vars'],len(nsamples)])

# Loop through all n values, create sample, evaluate model and estimate S1 & ST
for i in range(len(nsamples)):
    print('n= '+ str(nsamples[i]))
    # Generate samples
    sampleset = saltelli.sample(problem, nsamples[i],calc_second_order=False)
    # Run model for all samples
    output = [SA(*sampleset[j,:]) for j in range(len(sampleset))]
    # Perform analysis
    results = sobol.analyze(problem, np.asarray(output), calc_second_order=False,print_to_console=False)
    # Store estimates
    ST_estimates[:,i]=results['ST']
    S1_estimates[:,i]=results['S1']

np.save('ST_estimates.npy', ST_estimates)
np.save('S1_estimates.npy', S1_estimates)

S1_estimates = np.load('S1_estimates.npy')
ST_estimates = np.load('ST_estimates.npy')

# Generate figure showing evolution of indices
fig =  plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
handles = []
for j in range(problem['num_vars']):
    handles += ax1.plot(nsamples, S1_estimates[j,:], linewidth=5)
ax1.set_title('Evolution of S1 index estimates', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel('S1', fontsize=18)
ax1.set_xlabel('Number of samples (n)', fontsize=18)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
for j in range(problem['num_vars']):
    ax2.plot(nsamples, ST_estimates[j,:], linewidth=5)
ax2.set_title('Evolution of ST index estimates', fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylabel('ST', fontsize=18)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax2.set_xlabel('Number of samples (n)', fontsize=18)
fig.legend(handles, problem['names'], loc = 'right', fontsize=11)
plt.savefig('indexevolution.png')

# Calculate parameter rankings
S1_ranks = np.zeros_like(S1_estimates)
ST_ranks = np.zeros_like(ST_estimates)
for i in range(len(nsamples)):
    orderS1 = np.argsort(S1_estimates[:,i])
    orderST = np.argsort(ST_estimates[:,i])
    S1_ranks[:,i] = orderS1.argsort()
    ST_ranks[:,i] = orderST.argsort()
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: A sensitivity analysis. And when I run my script for analysis, I get this on my script which describe the function with the variable.

Comment: What function, module?

Comment: A function that includes loops (I do not know if we have the right but it did not put me error in the scipt function)